# Since and until when can I stay in China using a student visa?

Tags: student-visa, china, language-course

Suppose that you apply for a language program that lasts from 2018-03-10 to 2018-07-20. You are going to apply for the student visa (X2) to stay during the period.

However, I'm sure the legal stay does not start in 2018-03-10 and end in 2018-07-20. It is more like 2018-03-03 and 2018-07-27, or even longer period is allowed.

So after getting the visa, when can I start to enter in China and stay there? And until when must I leave China?

Or since the X2 visa is for people who study there within 180 days, can I decide any 180 days frame as far as it covers the language course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little less clear-cut. You have to arrive in China "reasonably" early enough to do the procedures to get your residence permit. It takes longer for first-timers like you. So you should generally give yourself about a month. But first enquire with the University when the registration starts. Before that date, you won't be able to do the paperwork. When you have that date, you can plan your arrival in China.

That's when your six months start: when you X2 visa is stamped in and invalidated (until you get your residence permit you cannot leave China; or more accurately you could leave, but cannot come back without applying for another X2). When you apply for the residence permit (and they'll keep your passport for a week or two), you'll get a six-month validity based on what the X2 visa and your arrival date.

Comment: I see. I thought the university handles everything after I register at the university. So even if my language course lasts only 18 weeks, can I stay 24 weeks? How about the case of short-term program (4 weeks)?

Comment: The Uni will provide you with documents, which you'll need to go to the Police and get your residence permit. But you have to do that yourself. And the Uni will write down your study period, which can influence the of the residence. The Police has final say.

Comment: So do all depend on the police on how many days I can stay there?

Comment: University + police, yes.